# Oracle PL/SQL : search record type value

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I am using Oracle 11G. Lets say I load data into a collection of `ROWTYPE`.

How can I extract a name or age from the collection `emp_tab` if I just pass `id` as the parameter without using any LOOP's?

```
  create table emp (id number, name varchar2(20), age number);
  insert into emp values(10,'Tom',20);
  insert into emp values(20,'Nicole',30);
  commit;
  select * from emp;

declare
       TYPE emp_t IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
       emp_tab emp_t;
begin
       select id,name,age bulk collect into emp_tab from emp;
           for idx in 1..emp_tab.count loop
           dbms_output.put_line(emp_tab(idx).name);
       end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to index your collection by `emp.id`, and to populate it you can't use `bulk collect` (at least not in 11g - it may be possible in [20c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-4B379569-4068-4DB1-9D69-E706F4AC5758)).

```
declare
    type emp_t is table of emp%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    emp_tab emp_t;
    
    idx emp.id%type;
begin
    for r in (
        select id, name, age
        from   emp
    )
    loop
        emp_tab(r.id).name := r.name;
        emp_tab(r.id).age := r.age;
    end loop;

    idx := emp_tab.first;

    while idx is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(emp_tab(idx).name);
        idx := emp_tab.next(idx);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks,I try it agian